# DateFormatter returning nil for valid String when decoding JSON

Tags: swift

I'm trying to decode a date of the format `2019-11-08T01:26:45+00:00` in Swift. Not sure if this is relevant, but it's a String taken from JSON. I've tried using `ISO8601DateFormatter`, setting the date format manually, etc., but nothing works.
(`response.timestamp` has the value `"2019-11-12T21:37:39+00:00"`, taken from JSON.)

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
self.timestamp = dateFormatter.date(from: response.timestamp)
```

When I build and run the application and set a breakpoint after initializing `date`, the value is always `nil`.

Comment: You need to post the actual code with the actual data that isn't working. We can't help if you only post code that works just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy This is the exact code that isn't working. It only works in Playground, not in the actual app.

Comment: So your real code in your running app is parsing a fixed string literal and not JSON?

Comment: Neither the fixed string literal nor the JSON string work. The string I'm using to test is just the same exact string as the JSON value.

Comment: Your date format is wrong `ZZZZZ` uses `Z` to represent UTC timezone. You need `xxxxx` which uses `+00:00` and don't set the locale to `.current` you should use `en_US_POSIX` locale

Comment: I hope you are setting the `dateDecodingStrategy` when decoding the JSON. This is not apparent in your code which is only the creation of your custom date formatter.

Answer (score 2):

The key observation is to make sure you’re using `en_US_POSIX` as the `locale`, as outlined in [Working With Fixed Format Date Representations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter#2528261):

```
let string = "2019-11-12T21:37:39+00:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

It’s worth noting though, while this formatter will successfully interpret date strings with `+00:00`, if and when you convert dates back to strings, it will use the literal `Z` common in ISO 8601/RFC 3339 dates, e.g. `"2019-11-12T21:37:39Z"`. If you really want your resulting strings (if you’re converting dates to strings at all) to use the `+00:00` convention, then you’ll want to use `xxxxx` instead of `ZZZZZ`. You’ll also want to specify a `timeZone` for your formatter, too:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date)            // "2019-11-12T21:37:39+00:00"
```

So use `ZZZZZ` if you want the standard `"2019-11-12T21:37:39Z"`, but use `xxxxx` if you want `"2019-11-12T21:37:39+00:00"`.

---

By the way, for more information on all the different permutation of `Z`, `ZZZZZ`, `X`, `xxxxx`, etc., see the time zone section of table at [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

---

> When I build and run the application and set a breakpoint after initializing date, the value is always `nil`.

By the way, always `print` (or `PO` in lldb) the value. Sometimes the inspector window in Xcode gets out of sync and shows `nil` when there really is some value there.

---

As jms said, if you’re using `JSONDecoder`, you probably shouldn’t use `date(from:)` or `string(from:)` at all. Make your property a `Date` type, and then give your decoder a `dateDecodingStrategy`:

```
let json = """
    {"date" : "2019-11-12T21:37:39+00:00"}
    """
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!

struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let date: Date
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

do {
    let object = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func convertDateString(dateString:String,dateFormat:String = "") -> String {
    if dateString.isEmpty {
        return "" 
    }
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX en_US_POSIX
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+s:s"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat.isEmpty ? "dd-MM-yyyy" : dateFormat
    dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale
    let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return dateStr
}
```

**usage** - your api response date in string format

```
let time1 = "2019-11-08T01:26:45+00:00"
print(convertDateString(dateString: time1,dateFormat: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"))
```

**OUTPUT --->>>**
Friday, Nov 8, 2019

Comment: Not `+s:s`. That’s just going to repeat seconds. E.g. the string generated by right now was `2019-11-13T15:01:43+43:43`.